# Why is my grid layout screwed up in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am just starting with android development. I have a grid view but two buttons on the bottom row of the grid layout have a very fine margin on top of them, which I am trying to eliminate. Even if I use the design tool and try to drag the buttons up a slim amount, they reset and go right back to having a thin layout on top.

[image: My bad Grid Layout]

The XML code for my layout is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#FD5F00"
        tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:text="0" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnclear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="AC"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textDirection="firstStrongLtr"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnnegative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnpercent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="%"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btndivide"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="÷"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="7"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textDirection="inherit"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="8"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="9"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="x"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="4"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="5"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsubtract"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="2"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="3"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnadd"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="+"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnpoint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="."
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="35sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="="
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

        </GridLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am new to android, and would appreciate any help that you could give for why the 0 and the = are not snapping to their proper grid location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: make sure all `Button`s have the same value for `android:layout_height`.

The `Button` between the "0" and the "=" has a different text size: `35sp` versus `28sp`. Since all the `Button`s have set their height to `wrap_content`, the neighbouring `Button`s don't fill the available space. So you see the background color above the smaller `Button`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using only `ConstraintLayout` with `GridLayout`. Check below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FD5F00"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="0" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDisplay">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnclear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textDirection="firstStrongLtr"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnnegative"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnpercent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="%"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndivide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="÷"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="7"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textDirection="inherit"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="8"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="9"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="x"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="4"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="5"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="6"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsubtract"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="2"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="3"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnpoint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="="
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

    </GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]